# How to target the 2nd index in pairs of arrays in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
options = [['first', 1], ['second', 2], ['third', 3], ['fourth', 4]]
```

Say i've selected 'second', how would I select it's paired value?

Comment: try `console.log(options[1][0])
console.log(options[1][1])`

Comment: You wouldn't use jQuery to manipulate arrays. *"Say i've selected 'second'"* - How did you do that? Show your current code.

Comment: So you selected the second element in the array by using `options[1]` which contains an array. Think about it, `['second', 2]` is just an array with two elements.

Answer (score 0):

```js
options = [
  ['first', 1],
  ['second', 2],
  ['third', 3],
  ['fourth', 4]
]

console.log(options[1][0])
console.log(options[1][1])

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  for (var ii = 0; ii < options[i].length; ii++) {
    console.log(options[i][ii])
  }
}
```

Try this samples and work your way to what you wanted